# Want to find discount price and original price while web scraping puma website?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyk7g.png)

I was web scraping through the puma website I wanted to find the original price and discount price separately, So whenever there is no discount price I just want to discount the price as 0 instead of not add any value is there any way I could do that?
link to the website: - https://in.puma.com/in/en/mens/mens-shoes

Whenever there is discount price + original price the div tag is

`'product-tile-price-new product-tile__price--new'` for discount price

`'product-tile-price-old product-tile__price--old'` for original price

When there is no discount the div tag is

`'product-tile-price-standard product-tile__price--standard'`

I could get both the discount price and original price by accessing there parent tag

```
a_price=soup.findAll('div',class_='product-tile-info-price product-tile__price')
a_price_list = []
for head in a_price:
    a_price_list.append((head.text).strip())
    
a_price_list
```

I will get
['₹2,149\n₹4,299',

'₹2,149\n₹4,299',

'₹3,369\n₹7,499',

'₹2,449\n₹3,499',

'₹9,999',

'₹6,999',

'₹2,449\n₹3,499',

'₹3,499\n₹6,999',

'₹8,999',

'₹8,249\n₹10,999',

'₹3,999\n₹7,999',

'₹5,999\n₹7,999',

'₹5,399\n₹8,999',

'₹3,249\n₹6,499',

'₹5,949\n₹6,999',

'₹4,249\n₹4,999',

'₹4,199\n₹6,999',

'₹2,399\n₹3,999',

'₹5,999',

'₹5,999',

'₹9,999',

'₹3,999\n₹7,999',

'₹3,499\n₹6,999',

'₹5,999\n₹11,999',

'₹5,499',

'₹2,469\n₹3,799',

'₹7,999',

'₹9,999',

'₹3,999',

'₹4,249\n₹4,999',

'₹3,249\n₹6,499',

'₹10,999',

'₹9,999',

'₹2,579\n₹4,299',

'₹2,999',

'₹3,499\n₹6,999']
So In the first index, there is a discount price and in the 2nd index, there is the original price, check out the 5th and 6th row , there is no discount price there so it's displaying the original price in 1st index. Instead, I want to print 0 as a discount price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try` and `except` block for finding tags for discount price is not there so it will go to `except` block and append 0 to list and you can find old price by tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res=requests.get("https://in.puma.com/in/en/mens/mens-shoes")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
prices=soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"product-tile-info-price"})
main_list=[]
for price in prices:
    try:
        discount_price=price.find("div",class_='product-tile-price-new').get_text(strip=True)
        main_list.append(discount_price)
        original_price=price.find("div",class_='product-tile-price-old').get_text(strip=True)
        main_list.append(original_price)
    except AttributeError:
        main_list.append(0)
        original_price=price.find("div",class_='product-tile-price-standard').get_text(strip=True)
        main_list.append(original_price)
```

Output:

```
['₹2,149',
 '₹4,299',
 '₹2,149',
 '₹4,299',
 '₹3,369',
 '₹7,499',
 '₹2,449',
 '₹3,499',
 0,
 '₹9,999',
 ....
```